# Adding a textview dynamically in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-fragments

I am new in android development..I am working with fragment.The problem i am facing right now is-I can't add view dynamically in fragment.When I tried to do this I got a nullpointerexception...My code snippet is as follows:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.connections_layout, container, false);
EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());

final int i = 5;
editText.setId(i); //Set id to remove in the future.
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
editText.setText("Hello");
Log.d("View","Start");
try{
    linearLayout.addView(editText);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The **connection_layout.xml** file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/connections"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:background="#FF0000" >

  </LinearLayout>
```

The fragment is a member of a tabgroup that belongs to fragment activity.What am i doing wrong in my code snippet? Any kind of help is appreciated.Thanks in advance...

Comment: I tried to refer the linearlayout with its id..But that approach was also unsuccessful...

Comment: where do you get NPE? (exact line)

Comment: @sandrstar, the line which is inside the try block generates the NPE..

Comment: @Dazzy_G,I have shared the codes with my questions..is there anything more I should provide for better understanding e.g. logcat...??

Comment: I meant what method is the snippet in

Answer (score 6):

Try this on fragment's `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 mContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connections_layout, null);
 LinearLayout linearLayout = mContainer.findViewById(R.id.connections);
 EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());

 final int i = 5;
 editText.setId(i); //Set id to remove in the future.
 editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 editText.setText("Hello");
 Log.d("View","Start");
 try{
        linearLayout.addView(editText);
 }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
 }

 return mContainer;
```

}